# How can I link two routers together wirelessly?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I'm sharing the Internet with a neighbour (I pay a bit of the cost). Unfortunately the connection only works well in certain areas of my house (those places closest to the wireless router.)

I want to try and put a wireless router I have in the room that performs the best and then connect this wireless router to my neighbour's router, then broadcast the second router throughout the house to boost the connection. Will this be possible?

Comment: Do you currently own a wireless router or you are yet to purchase it?

Comment: If you do own a router check if it has a repeater mode. Most routers these days have this feature. The repeater mode makes your router function as a signal booster(i.e. it will get the signal from the main router and extend the signal in your house) for a single wireless LAN network.

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want is an extender. It works by picking up the signal from the router and than emitting it back out at renewed strength. Plus, they're usually cheaper than routers.

Answer (score 0):

These are also sometimes called access points.  Are either of the routers a linksys wrt54g?  There is an open source firmware available that lets this thing do everything for you include wash your dishes!

Comment: Using that feature of the DD-WRT open source firmware feature halves your speed though, because the radio has to constantly switch between AP and infrastructure mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact situation as you describe. I bought an [ASUS Access point AP WL-330gE](http://www.asus.com/Networks/WiFi_Networking/WL330gE/). It has many features, one of wich is extending a given LAN ore wireless LAN.

According to the illustration on the linked page I used "Gateway mode": It took the neighbour's wireless LAN to set up an own WLAN cell in my rooms, routing my wireless LAN to my neighbour's. Thus, all my gadgets had full signal strength. Additionally, the AP has one LAN socket for one device without wireless LAN support. This single port can be extended by a switch to connect more than a single wired device.

The AP solved all my connection problems with all my devices.